# Get an HTML form's POST variables with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the POST variables from a form, using ExactTarget's scripting language, AMPScript? I'm seeing how to get parameters via query strings, but seeing how I'm building a login page, passing username/passwords through query strings isn't really an option.

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can get these using [**RequestParameter()**](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#RequestParameter) function.

It might even work with the GET parameters, but not 100% sure this is the case (if it is you can use one function to handle both methods in one code).